# Drawing a quadratic function in mixed effect model

Tags: r, regression, lme4, quadratic

It's a bit of a long question so thanks for bearing with me.

Here's my data

https://www.dropbox.com/s/jo22d68a8vxwg63/data.csv?dl=0

I constructed a mixed effect model

```
library(lme4)
mod <- lmer(sqrt(y) ~ x1 + I(x1^2) + x2 + I(x2^2) + x3 + I(x3^2) + x4 + I(x4^2) + x5 + I(x5^2) + 
      x6 + I(x6^2) + x7 + I(x7^2) + x8 +  I(x8^2) + (1|loc) + (1|year), data = data)
```

All the predictors are standardised and I am interested in knowing how does `y` changes with changes in `x5`while keeping other variables at their mean values (equal to 0 since all the variables are standardised).

This is how I do it.

```
# make all predictors except x5 equal to zero 

data$x1<-0
data$x2<-0
data$x3<-0
data$x4<-0
data$x6<-0
data$x7<-0
data$x8<-0

# Use the predict function 
 library(merTools)
fitted <- predictInterval(merMod = mod, newdata = data, level = 0.95, n.sims = 1000,stat = "median",include.resid.var = TRUE)
```

Now I want to plot the fitted as a quadratic function of `x5`. I do this:

```
i<-order(data$x5)  

plot(data$x5[i],fitted$fit[i],type="l")
```

I expected this to produce a plot of `y` as a quadratic function of `x5`. But As you can see, I get the following plot which does not have any quadratic curve. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

[image: This is what I get]

Comment: Yes. I have it.

Comment: I have just modified my question to reflect what I used to predict using the merTools

Comment: It's a bit confusing for me. If I extract the coefficient of x5 from mod and draw the quadratic myself, will it account for the fact that other predictors are held constant. Sorry my maths/statistics is a bit weak. hence the confusion.

Comment: Will it be possible for you to post this as a solution, so that I can mark it and see if I have got it right. Thanks

Comment: `plot(data$x5, 49.59507 + data$x5 * -1.09963 + data$x5^2 * -1.28696)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where `predictInterval` comes from, but you can do this with `predict`. The trick is just to make sure you set your random effects to 0. Here's how you can do that

```
newdata <- data
newdata[,paste0("x", setdiff(1:8,5))] <- 0
y <- predict(mod, newdata=newdata, re.form=NA)
plot(data$x5, y)
```

The `re.form=NA` part drops out the random effect

[image]

Comment: Thanks. `predictInterval` comes from library(merTools)